# Image patterns with nested loops

Tags: php

Currently i'm practicing some exercises with loops and nested loops. I already created a code to "draw"  such pattern:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

and to make it i wrote such code:

```
$n = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $n; $j++) {
        if ($j <= $i) {
            echo '*';
        }
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Now i'm trying to figure out how to "draw" such pattern:

```
* 2 3 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* * * 4 5
* * * * 5
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 5
* * * 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* 2 3 4 5
```

The only thing i concluded so far is to use something similar as in previous code but i'm really out of idea how to implement it. Could you help me on this?

Comment: Just add an `else` clause that echoes the column number instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$n = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $n; $j++) {
        if ($j <= $i) {
            echo '*';
        }
        else {
            echo $j;
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
for ($i = $n; $i > 0; $i--) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $n; $j++) {
        if ($j <= $i) {
            echo '*';
        }
        else {
            echo $j;
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

See the difference in incremental and decremental loops

Comment: Thanks, that's 99% of what i needed. Only thing to change was line 3rd, it should look like this: for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) { Tiny detail but draws one more line full of stars.